# How can I capture network packets per PID?

Tags: linux, networking

Anyone know an easy way to ask Linux to "display every internet packet to/from google chrome" or "display every internet packet to/from telnet process with PID 10275"?

The telnet example is not too useful, since I can just use wireshark or tcpdump to see all TCP conversations involving port 23. That and nobody uses telnet anymore. But sniffing all packets to/from complex applications which use many ports seems like a useful thing.

I found some related answers exploring different ways to corroborate ports and PIDs (or programs names) and such, but nothing about packets

- [How to tie a network connection to a PID without using lsof or netstat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838317/how-to-tie-a-network-connection-to-a-pid-without-using-lsof-or-netstat)
- [How I can get ports associated to the application that opened them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306138/how-i-can-get-ports-assosiated-to-aplication-that-oppened-them/3308198)
- [How to do like "netstat -p", but faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056850/how-to-do-like-netstat-p-but-faster/4057150)

Looks like someone might have been willing to pay for this answer a while back:

- http://www.freelancer.com/projects/Perl-CGI-C-C/tcpdump-PID-relation.html

[NetHogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) is useful for quickly seeing what programs are creating traffic over an interface, but it doesn't have a way to capture packets.

Comment: Hrm, should I ask on serverfault instead?

Comment: This probably belongs on SuperUser, actually. An interesting question. You could use WireShark to filter out HTTP requests, but you'd have to hook into the kernel drivers to filter packets based on PIDs

Comment: It's a bit of a complex issue - sockets aren't owned by PIDs; you can pass them from one process to another. If process A opens a socket, it can pass it over to process B then exit - if you're filtering on process A's PID, what happens now?

Comment: I was going to suggest using `dtrace` to watch syscalls like `write`, `send`, `sendto`, but AFAIK `dtrace` hasn't made it to Linux. Perhaps you can use a similar syscall logging tool?

Answer (score 20):

Not directly a tcpdump, but can give you info about the network traffic, check https://bytefreaks.net/gnulinux/how-to-capture-all-network-traffic-of-a-single-process

```
strace -f -e trace=network -s 10000 <PROCESS WITH ARGUMENTS>;
```

If the process is already started and you know its PID you can use the following
1

```
strace -f -e trace=network -s 10000 -p <PID>;
```

Another alternative is more complex, using network namespaces, check the above link or use the tool [nsntrace](https://github.com/jonasdn/nsntrace), but either can only work on new process, you can not change existent process network namespaces (AFAIK)

UPDATE:
you can also install the tool bpfcc-tools (search for your distro, many have it included already) and use the command `sudo tcptracer-bpfcc -v -p (PID)`
While this will not show the packets, it will list network connections for that pid. You can remove the `-p (PID)` to list all connections per process. This may be useful for those tracking short live connections, not the network payload.

Comment: You can move process to another chroup

Comment: @Et7f3XIV any reference how to do that is always useful

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/admin-guide/cgroup-v2.html A process can be migrated into a cgroup by writing its PID to the target cgroup’s “cgroup.procs” file

Comment: Another link that explains practical commands to manipulate cgroup v2 https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.9/admin-guide/cgroup-v1/cgroups.html#how-do-i-use-cgroups

Answer (score 2):

I would use `lsof -i` to get the port numbers associated with the application I want.
The code would be like this:

```
process=firefox
for _port in `lsof -i | grep $process | cut -d' ' -f18 | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d'-' -f1`
do
    port=$_port
    [[ "$_port" == +([a-zA-Z]) ]] && port=`cat /etc/services  | grep '^$_port' | cut -d' ' -f12 | cut -d'/' -f1 | uniq | head -n 1`

    echo "tcpdump -w ${port}.pcap port $port &"
    tcpdump -w ${port}.pcap port $port &
done
```

Note that the output of the commands might be different on different versions/distributions. Therefore, you'd better check the right fileds are cut before using the script.

Also, this script does not monitor the ports that are opened later. For that, I would consider a more complicated script that checks ports regularly (using something like `watch`)

And remember to kill all of the tcpdump processes afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I wanted to capture syslog traffic but only from rsyslog. It only had one listening port under `lsof -p $(pidof rsyslog)` and always used that as the source port, so I was able to get the packets using:

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -A "host 10.0.0.100 and dst port 514 and src port $(lsof -i 4 -a -p `pidof rsyslogd` | grep -Po '(?<=\*:)[0-9]*') and udp"
```

The [grep uses a positive lookbehind assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15136585/17373) to turn the *:portnumber into just the port number.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/comboshreddies/py-strace2pcap

```
do 
strace -f -yy -xx -ttt -T | ./py-strace2pcap.py record_file.pcap
```

Answer (score -3):

Tcpdump can tell you the PID/process a packet comes from/to. 
Throw '-k NP' in your options.

Version supported: tcpdump version 4.3.0 -- Apple version 56

Comment: Question was asked for Linux. There is no such option in Linux's tcpdump which shows the PID info.

Comment: tcpdump 4.9.2 doesn't have `-k` option neither, on Linux.

Comment: 2022 update: tcpdump 4.9.3 (rhel8) still doesn't have `-k`.