# Capture pid of process using port 6881 only once every 15 min

Tags: port, pid, tcpdump

I can see from a tcpdump that an internal linux server is trying to contact an outside computer approximately every 15 min: one udp-packet on port `6881` (bittorrent), that's all.

As this server isn't supposed to contact anyone, I want to find out what evil soul generated this packet, i.e. I need some information about the process (e.g. `pid`, file, ...).

Because the timespan is so short, I can't use `netstat` or `lsof`.

The process is likely to be active about half of a microsecond, then it gets a `destination unreachable (port unreachable)` from firewall.

I have ssh access to the machine.

[How can I capture network packets per PID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842533/how-can-i-capture-network-packets-per-pid) suggests to use the `tcpdump` option `-k`, however, linux `tcpdump` has no such option.

Comment: Maybe have a look at the HoneProject?  https://github.com/HoneProject/Linux-Sensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with TCPDump, obviously, but you can do this from the host itself.  Especially since it's UDP with no state, and since you can't predict when the process will be listening, you should look into using the kernel audit capabilities.  For example:

```
 auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64 -F a0=2 -F a1\&=2 -S socket -k SOCKET
```

This instructs the kernel to generate an audit event whenever there is a socket call.  With this done, you can then wait until you see the suspicious packet leave the machine and then use `ausearch` to track down not only the process, but the binary that made the call.